# How to Rotate Orthographic View Along Z-Axis

Tags: 3d-view, orthographic

When I looking directly down at my object in orthographic view, how to I rotate the view along the Z-Axis only?

In other words, how to do I roll the perspective clockwise or counterclockwise?

I vaguely remember there being a shortcut for this but I can't remember what it is.

Comment: Shift+4or6 on the numpad to rotate it. Ctrl+4or6 to move it sideways and 8or2 for up and down. These also work outside orthographic

Comment: Thanks for this.  Actually holding Shift+4or6 is a better solution for me than Gordon's. If you want to write it as an answer I'll mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortcut to rotate clockwise is <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd>, counter-clockwise is <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd>. Then you rotate the view around the selected object's origin or ther median point when multiple objects are selected.

However, if you have Blender at default settings, it can be that it automatically switches to *Perspective*. To switch back to *Orthographic* you can press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>.

If you don't want Blender to switch automatically between the perspective and orthographic views, you can disable it in the *Preferences* under *Navigation* > *Orbit & Pan* > *Auto*.

But note: when you disable it, it also does not switch to perspective view when for example you are in orthographic top down view and start rotating the view by dragging the <kbd>MMB</kbd>. And if you are in perspective view, it does not automatically switch back to orthographic if you e.g. press <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> for top down view.

[image: auto perspective]

Comment: Gordon you are a life saver, thank you!  It was the Auto Perspective switch that was messing me up.  I wish it would just stay in Ortho when you hit 4 or 6, as opposed to having to turning off the feature altogether, which is not ideal for me.  But knowledge is power, so thank you!